# Как оптимизировать структуру программы для заранее неизвестных входных данных? С++

Tags: c++, функции, структуры-данных, полиморфизм

Есть класс "модель" в котором есть список с объектами унаследованными от абстрактного класса "слой", наследники "слоя" могут хранить в себе многомерные матрицы, в классе "модель" есть метод начинающий расчет некоторых математических задач от слоя к слою, этот метод принимает на вход ту самую стартовою многомерную матрицу, проблема в том, что список со "слоями" формируется динамически и заранее неизвестно какая размерность матрицы будет в первом "слое", как можно покрасивее организовать вход данных, чтобы не плодить кучу перегрузок? Ведь предполагается, что размерность может в идеале быть любой.

Comment: К тому же,  вы очень заняты, и у вас нет времени предоставлять   класс "модель",  абстрактный класс "слой",  его наследники. Все правильно, а то эти отвечающие совсем обленились, хотят только копировать,  пускай сами и напишут...

Comment: Мне бы хотелось саму концепцию узнать решения таких проблем, на словах, основную суть я изложил. Я бы скинул код, но у меня его практически нет, просто на этапе проектирования возникла такая проблема, и хотелось бы знать как люди поступают в подобных случаях.

Comment: не объязательно скидывать  готовый код, можно скинуть классы  без определения и привести пример. А то многие могут не правильно понять ваши намерения, и , следовательно ответ  не устроит вас, и начнутся бесконечные выяснения  в  чате. Я один из тех, кому ответ кажется неоднозначным